# Recover overwritten git commit lost by force push

Tags: git

I was writing a README.md file in the remote server and completed that one, but I accidentally did a force push to the remote by using `git push origin master` and now the `README.md` is gone

Is there a way I can retrieve that commit? I have written a very long README.md file and really want to see if I can get it back :(

I was looking though the `git fsck` and couldn't find the one about the README.md that I have commit from the remote server on github.com

Comment: Did you do `writing a README.md file in the remote server` in github or your own server?

Comment: @pktangyue it was on github server and it was showing on the commit section there

Comment: You may goto the index page of github to check if there any information of you lost commit.

Comment: How can I find that @pktangyue on the index page?

Comment: In `Public Activity` page, you may see something like this: 
XXX pushed to master at XX/XXX
  d506bb1 Update README.md. And `d506bb1` is your lost commit.

Comment: Thanks to you I found it there :D

Comment: @pktangyue: You should submit an answer for the github solution and Ali should mark it correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Public Activity** of github, you may see something like this:

```
XXX pushed to master at XX/XXX 
d506bb1 Update README.md.
```

And here `d506bb1` is your lost commit.

Answer (score 10):

If it existed in some working copy, go to that repo and use `git reflog` to find a revision that contained it and `git checkout` to go to that revision (outside of any branch).  Then you can copy the file out wherever you want.

If the server is bare it is probably still an object on the *server* but no kind of `git fetch` will copy it to any other repo because there are no references to it.  In that case you'll need access to the bare repo to run your `git fsck` directly.

Comment: I have no luck on the `git reflog` it doesn't have that in my local machine :(, and I did try `git fsck` I didn't go through all of them yet, but really there are a lot there :(

Comment: I was digging around the activity page of mine and found the file :D

Comment: you saved me hours or rework