# git: Restore remote changes before force push

Tags: git

Consider a branch XYZ in some repo. My local XYZ was in sync with the remote.

A fellow developer pushed some commits to the branch. I made some local changes on XYZ without pulling the other developer's commits first, and then force-pushed (I had to force-push since I had edited some previous commits).

So now, the other developer's commits on the remote XYZ were overwritten by my XYZ's git history.

How can I get their commits back?

---

**EDIT:**

The problem I'm facing is that their commits were never on my local branch, so I can not use `reflog` or `checkout`. I'm aware that I can see their changes on the remote repo but I'd like to know how to bring those commits back into the history.

More precisely, I would like to know if there is a way that I can "insert" their commits back into the history and then apply my changes over that (in a similar way in which `rebase` works - remote commits are brought to the local repo and then local commits are applied on top).

---

I can still see the changes of their commits on the remote repo so I'm guessing something like this happens:

Let's say my local XYZ and remote XYZ have the commits `A-B-C-D`, i.e. they're synced till `D`. Then, the other developer pushes more commits and the remote becomes `A-B-C-D-E-F` i.e. the head points to F. Then, I make changes in my local XYZ to make it `A-B-C-D-G-H-I` and then force push it. On the remote XYZ, `A-B-C-D-E-F` is now "overwritten" by `A-B-C-D-G-H-I`, i.e. the head now points to `I`, even though `E-F` still exist. So is there any way for me to access `E-F`?

Locally, using git, I would've searched through `reflog` and used `checkout`. Is there anything equivalent to this to access commits on remote repos?

Comment: Check the answer  there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930685/recover-overwritten-git-commit-lost-by-force-push

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover overwritten git commit lost by force push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930685/recover-overwritten-git-commit-lost-by-force-push)

Comment: In summary, you need to check the solution on public repo if you did not "git fetch" before push force.

Comment: An extra note : start using `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force`. You can define an alias for it : `git config --global alias.pushf 'push --force-with-lease'`