# Unable to do git revert after forced push to remote repository

Tags: git, github

I created a new folder in my system. There, I did `git init` and then added remote origin like

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/usrname/reponame
```

Then, without taking pull, I forcefully pushed my local change to existing git repo using `-f` command which deleted previous data and stored new one.

Now I want my previous data of that git repo. Just after `git push`, I executed `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, but got this error:

[image: Error message]

I also tried `git reset --hard last_commit_id`, which I got after forced update but getting error like `fatal: ambiguous argument '0...4': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.

I even did `git log --all` or `git reflog`, but not getting previous commit IDs and data.

Comment: check your remote repo if it contains old commits.

Comment: no its not showing old commits. What can i do?@Chandan

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930685/recover-overwritten-git-commit-lost-by-force-push).

Comment: @Chandan thanks but couldn't get any index page or public activity page in github as suggested in the answer of that post. do you have any idea where will i get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HEAD~1` does not exist locally, since you just initialized your local repository.

Assuming the remote repository was not a new repository, but one where multiple pushes did occur (before your last forced push, which overrode everything), you could try and retrieve the *previous* push (the one done before your force push)

For that, you can use the [poor man reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309), which uses the GitHub API to retrieve the public push event and its associated SHA1. (`curl -u <username>:<token> https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/events`)
Replace `<user>` by your GitHub username, and `<repo>` by your repository name.
Use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) as `<token>`.

You would then need, as mentioned in the previous link, to create a GitHub branch "`tmp`" to reference that old SHA1 (still using GitHub API).
From there, you can fetch, and reset your local `master` to the fetched `origin/tmp`

```
git switch -C master origin/tmp
```

---

The OP used the [blobs / get a blob](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#get-a-blob) GitHub  API to

> see full details of my last to last commit using SHA.
> In full details, I got `html_ulr` which took me to a GitHub page which where I was able to download the files

Answer (score 0):

Instead doing a reset, you could perform a revert on the branch to revert the commit that was pushed forcefully. Something like

git revert HEAD~1

git push origin master

Comment: Thanks but Getting error fatal: bad revision 'HEAD~1' while executing 1st command